# how to save previous frame in an array and compare it with current frame in python

Tags: python, object, duplicates, comparison, frames

i want to remove the duplication of objects, so when the camera opens it captures the first frame and save on the disk, than untill next object appears in the scene it saves the next object frame (does not save the same frame consecutively).

i have written a code to compare two consecutive frames of webcam, i want to store one frame in an array (max limit 3) to compare it with current frame. so the first frame will be saved on the disk and it compares untill the next object appears(used threshold value for this purpose)

How can i save the frame to an array and compare with current frame?

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity
import imutils
import sys
import datetime
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (True):
      # Capture frame-by-frame
      ret, frame1 = cap.read(0)  # first image
      time.sleep(1/50)          # slight delay
      ret, frame2 = cap.read(0)  # second image 
      gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

      # compute the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) between the two
      # images, ensuring that the difference image is returned
      (score, diff) = structural_similarity (gray1, gray2, full=True)
      diff = (diff * 255).astype ("uint8")
      print ("SSIM: {}".format (score))

      # threshold the difference image, followed by finding contours to
      # obtain the regions of the two input images that differ
      thresh = cv2.threshold (diff, 0, 255,
                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

      if np.mean (thresh) < 0.4 :
           print ("New object Detected")
           date_string = datetime.datetime.now ( ).strftime ("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
           cv2.imwrite ('img/img-' + date_string + '.png', frame2[y:y+h+30, x:x+w+30])

      # Display the resulting frame
      cv2.imshow ('frame1', frame1)
      cv2.imshow('frame2', frame2)
      cv2.imshow ("Diff", diff)
      cv2.imshow ("Thresh", thresh)

      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break

 # When everything is done, release the capture
 video_capture.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not hard.

Actually, you can get the image as a NumPy array.
The shape is (720, 1280, 3).

[image]

To save it, try this

```
      ...
      ret, frame1 = cap.read(0)  # first image
      
      print(frame1.shape)
      rgb_frame1 = frame1[..., ::-1]
      im = Image.fromarray(rgb_frame1)
      im.save("your_file.jpeg")
      
      time.sleep(1/50)          # slight delay
      ...
```

Note: you need to change the channel order or you will get a blue image. Because the original channel is in BRG format.

[image]

Then you can store the frame:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Frank, i am still confused that how can i compare it with frame2 and stop the duplication of objects saving on the disk. can you please help how can i write to the compare it to find the similarity?

Comment: @SadiaLakho For this problem, I suggest you read some paper to get some ideas.

Comment: I did read the papers and i have idea, problem is i don't know how to implement in python, as i am beginner in python. @Frank Actually this code will be implemented on face mask detection to do the matching of same faces, so the same face cannot be saved multiple time, as face recognition is a challenge on masked faces that's why applying similarity index. i have done the face mask detection part.